# Understanding the window coordinates' interpretation in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I was trying to understand OpenGL a bit more deep and I got stuck with below issue.

This segment describes my understanding, and the outputs are as assumed.

```
glViewport(0, 0 ,800, 480);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-400.0, 400.0, -240.0, 240.0, 1.0, 100.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -1);
glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 1);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-128, -128,  0.0f); 
    glVertex3f(128, -128,  0.0f);
    glVertex3f(128,  128,  0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-128,  128,  0.0f);
glEnd();
```

The window coordinates (Wx, Wy, Wz) for the above snippet are

- (272.00000286102295, 111.99999332427979, 5.9604644775390625e-008)
- (527.99999713897705, 111.99999332427979, 5.9604644775390625e-008)
- (527.99999713897705, 368.00000667572021, 5.9604644775390625e-008)
- (272.00000286102295, 368.00000667572021, 5.9604644775390625e-008)

I did a glReadPixels() and dumped to a bmp file. In the image I get a quad as expected with the (Wx, Wy) mentioned above ( since incase of images, the origin is at the top left, while verifying the bmp image I took care of subtracting the the window height i.e 480). This output was as per my understanding - (Wx, Wy) will be used as a 2D coordinate and Wz will be used for depth purpose.

Now comes the issue. I tried the below code snippet.

```
glViewport(0, 0 ,800, 480);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-400.0, 400.0, -240.0, 240.0, 1.0, 100.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(100, 0, -1);
glRotatef(30, 0, 1, 0);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-128, -128,  0.0f); 
    glVertex3f(128, -128,  0.0f);
    glVertex3f(128,  128,  0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-128,  128,  0.0f);
glEnd()
```

The window coordinates for the above snippet are

- (400.17224205479812, 242.03174613770986, 1.0261343689191909)
- (403.24386530741430, 238.03076912806583, 0.99456100555566640)
- (403.24386530741430, 241.96923087193414, 0.99456100555566640)
- (400.17224205479812, 237.96825386229017, 1.0261343689191909)

When I dumped output to a bmp file, I expected to have a very small parallelogram(approx like a  4 x 4 square transformed to a parallelogram) based on the above (Wx, Wy). But this was not the case. The image had a different set of coordinates as below

- (403, 238)
- (499, 113)
- (499, 366)
- (403, 241)

I have mentioned the coordinates in CW direction as seen on the image.

I got lost here. Can anyone please help in understanding what and why it is happening in the 2nd case??
How come I got a point (499, 113) on the screen when it was no where in the calculated window coordinates?

I used gluProject() to the window coordinates.

Note : I'm using OpenGL 2.0. I'm just trying to understand the concepts here, so please don't suggest to use versions > OpenGL 3.0.

---

edit

This is an update for the answer posted by derhass

The homogenous coordinates after the projection matrix for the 2nd case is as follows

- (-0.027128123630699719, -0.53333336114883423, -66.292930483818054, -63.000000000000000)
- (0.52712811245482882, -0.53333336114883423, 64.292930722236633, 65.00000000000000)
- (0.52712811245482882, 0.53333336114883423, 64.292930722236633, 65.000000000000000)
- (-0.027128123630699719, 0.53333336114883423, -66.292930483818054, 63.000000000000000)

So here for the vertices where z > -1, the vertices will get clipped at the near plane. When this is the case, shouldn't GL use the projected point at z = -1 plane?

Comment: "So here for the vertices where z > -1, the vertices will get clipped at the near plane. When this is the case, shouldn't GL use the projected point at z = -1 plane?" You are misinterpreting that clip space coordinates. The viewing frustum is [-w,w] in all three dimensions there, so the z=-1 plane is totally meaningless here. The clipping will of course generate vertices which, if one would convert them to eye space, would lie on the z=-1 plane there.

Comment: thanks for pin pointing that the viewing volume is [-w,w] in all directions before perspective divide. I never thought about it that way. I only had in mind that the viewing volume will be [-1,1] in all directions after perspective divide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are missing here is *clipping*.

After this

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-400.0, 400.0, -240.0, 240.0, 1.0, 100.0);
```

you basically have a camera at origin, looking along the `-z` direction, and the near plane at `z=-1`, the far plane at `z=-100`. Now you draw a 128x128 square rotated at 30 degrees aliong the `y` (up) axis, and shifted by -1 along `z` (and 100 along `x`, but that is not the crucial point here). Since You rotated the square around its center point, the z value for two of the points will be way before the near plane, while the other two should fall into the frustum. (And you can also see that as those two points match your expectations).

Now directly projecting all 4 points to window space is not what GL does. It transforms the points to `clip space`, intersects the primitives with all 6 sides of the viewing frustum and finally projects the clipped primitives into window space for rasterization.

The projection you did is actually only meaningful for points which lie inside the frustum. Two of your points lie *behind* the camrea, and projecting points behind the camera will create an mirrored image of these points in front of the camera.

Comment: asuming that the asker has calculated his values correctly: Shouldn't clipping produce new points only inside of the unclipped polygon? e.g. his x-values range from 400-403, how can clipping create a point at x=499?

Comment: @BDL: No, it shouldn't. It should do so only _before_ the perspective divide (and the clip space is named that way for a reason), but not in window space. You could also clip in eye space, of course. So if the asker would intersect that rotated square with the z=-1 plane, and project the resulting points to window space, he/she should also get exactly the points the GL produced.

Comment: @derhass: Can you post a link or explain more about creation of the mirrored image for the points in front of the camera??

Comment: @derhass:Now I wrote some code to get the vertices at each stage, and after the projection matrix is applied, in the second case, 2 vertices have z coordinate which is in front of the camera. So they get clipped by the shape of the frustum. But when geometry is clipped, shouldn't it look a geometry which was cut in piece? For ex. if you rotate a square(which is near to camera) in x axis, you don't get a full parallelogram, but a clipped one, like a half parallelgram.I didn't understand the point where you talk about the creation of mirrored image for points in front of cam.

Comment: @RedDragon: I don't know why you expect a parallelogram. First of all, you don't rorate around `x`, but `y`. Now if you use a perspective projection on a square which is rotated so that it will extend into the `z` dimensin, you should expect a trapezoid. In your case, even after clipping, you still get a perfectly symmetrical trapezoid. As I side note: your view frustum uses an extremely wide fov close to 180 degrees, which will result in a very unrealistic looking perepctive distortion.

Comment: In the clip space, the homogeneous coordinate w and the z coordinate were both negative. After perspective divide, z becomes positive. So if one looks only at the output of gluProject(), it deceives them that the point is in front of camera.